# sqlite3.2.8 unknown command or invalid arguments: "backup"

Tags: sqlite

I just do the following code:

```
$ cd /path-to-repository/.svn
$ mv wc.db wc.db.old
$ sqlite3 wc.db.old
sqlite> .backup main wc.db
sqlite> .exit
```

But the code `sqlite> .backup main wc.db` error: `unknown command or invalid arguments:  "backup". Enter ".help" for help`

I also have try `sqlite3 wc.db.old ".backup main wc.db"`, it has the same error.

sqlite3 dont have the command backup? Is any idea?

Comment: That SQLite version is over ten years old.

Comment: @CL. so, is it the version problem, the version is too old?